# Universal/generic boxing from Any to AnyRef

Tags: scala, boxing

Is it possible to force runtime boxing in scala dynamically? I would like a function:

```
    def box(value :Any) :AnyRef
```

or

```
    def box[T](value :T) :AnyRef
```

I have a generic class which may be parameterized with AnyVals but need to pass them to legacy java methods accepting collections of objects. Of course, I could implement it myself with pattern matching, but it's a bit annoying to have to do it time and time again, and it wouldn't work for user value classes.

**Edit**

The answer turned out as simple as surprising. Now, can I do it through reflection? Assume

```
class Box[T :TypeTag](private var value :T) {
    def get :T = value
    def set(o :Any) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to do a safe set, checking in the runtime if o is a subclass of T like this:

```
runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).classSymbol(o.getClass).toType <:< typeOf[T]
```

Unfortunately, typeOf[T] for Box[Long] will be a primitive, and the following check will fail on java.lang.Long, which is the runtime type of elements of Seq[Long] for example. Bottom line, when using generics with AnyVals, the compiler sometimes boxes them making runtime class checks unpredictible.

Comment: Your added part doesn't seem to be about boxing from `Any` to `AnyRef`. (Looks like it has more to do with unboxing?) How about making it a second, separate question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just cast to `AnyRef` with `asInstanceOf` and Scala will turn it into an `AnyRef`:

```scala
scala> val x = 13
x: Int = 13

scala> val xBoxed = x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
xBoxed: AnyRef = 13

scala> xBoxed.getClass()
res0: Class[_ <: AnyRef] = class java.lang.Integer
```

For value classes, this will box it in an instance of the value class, instead of the Java class. You could use a generic trait to be able to get the Java boxed versions from your value classes, without using reflection. For example:

```scala
trait ValueClass[T] extends Any {
  def value: T
  def javaBoxed: AnyRef = value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
}

case class MyInt(value: Int) extends AnyVal with ValueClass[Int]

case class MyReal(asDouble: Double) extends AnyVal with ValueClass[Double] {
  def value = asDouble
}
```

However, this requires you mix your trait into all your value classes. For value classes that extend [`Product`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.Product), like all case classes do, there's a quicker way using `productElement`:

```scala
def javaBox(x: Product): AnyRef = {
  if (x.productArity == 1) x.productElement(0).asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
  else x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] // or throw an exception if you prefer
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks to me like both methods (mix-in trait and `Product`) cause Scala to do its boxing, meaning when called on an unboxed value, the value goes from unboxed → Scala boxed → unboxed → Java boxed, instead of straight to the Java boxed value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It is quite amusing though, as `42.asInstanceOf[AnyVal]` will produce a compiler warning saying it's always false, but will evaluate to `true`. Also, it doesn't seem to work for user value classes. I added a bonus question to the original question for additional credit.